# Grails, Using read() on domain class with composite id

Tags: database, grails, groovy

I have a nice little domain class which consists of three Integers but no primary key (because of poor database design...which re-writing is out of the question):

```
class Domain implements Serializable {

   Integer foo
   Integer bar
   Integer flag

    static mapping = {
        table 'domain'
        version false

        id  composite: ['foo', 'bar']
        foo column: 'foo_nbr'
        flag    column: 'value_I_want_flag'
        bar column: 'bar_nbr'   
    }
}
```

I want be able to access the flag through the read function using the composite id of foo and bar

such as

```
Integer yayFlag = Domain.read(foo, bar).flag
```

Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: You should remove `String id` since the id is a composite and that field won't be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs on this](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#compositePrimaryKeys), you should be able to reference via the `get()` syntax with a prototype object:

```
def d = Domain.get(new Domain(foo: 23, bar: 999))
```

Note that it also advises implementing `hashCode()` and `equals()` (using the id component fields), and making the class `Serializable`.

If `read()` is a requirement, you could try the same for that, but I haven't searched the source to know if that will work (the reference docs for [`get()`](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/get.html) don't actually explicitly show you can do the above, so not saying that in [`read()`](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/read.html) reference docs is not conclusive).  I've been away from Grails for a while, but you might also try `discard()` after your `get()` to avoid a DB write at flush.

Comment: Ah yeah for the class to even compile I had to make it Serializable.  And the reason I was using read because of how powerful get is with the DB overwrites. I didn’t know about discard() that is very interesting! I couldn’t get anything but null, based on creating a new instance of it based on foo and bar though.

Comment: do you have equals() and hashcode() defined with (just) the id compenents?  it's conceivable there is some caching of instances based on this, though I wouldn't think that'd be an issue on the first get().

Comment: I do not have hasCode() and equals() methods I'm looking into them though right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, you need to create a prototype instance as Brian mentioned. You can create a helper method with the syntax you want to use that does the work for you:

```
static Domain read(int foo, int bar) {
   read new Domain(foo: foo, bar: bar)
}
```

You would probably want a similar `get` method too.

Comment: I tried both creating this helper method with the prototype instance  and using read and trying with get as well. I kept getting null.  So I decided to use Domain.findWhere(foo: foo, bar: bar) and I then got the expected result.  Are you able to get read to work?